# In R, convert/split 1-column dataframe into 4 columns based on splitting content in strings

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, strsplit

This feels like a fairly difficult data manipulation / dataframe fixup issue in R. We have the following messy dataframe, currently organized such that multiple columns of information are packed into the `X2` column. Using fake names, emails, phone numbers in the example below:

```
coach_info <- structure(list(X1 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_), X2 = c("TBA\r\n Head Coach", "Bobby Flowes\r\n Associate Head Women's Basketball Coach", 
"Jimmy Jimm\r\n Assistant Women's Basketball Coach", "Rod Barber\r\n Head Men's Basketball Coach\r\n       (123) 456-7890Tom.Tommy@abc.edu", 
NA, "Gabens Spar\r\n Men's Basketball Graduate Assistant Coachgabensspar@gmail.edu", 
"A.B. Better\r\n Head Women's Basketball Coach/Head Men's Golf Coach/Sports Information Associateabbetter@gmail.edu\r\n   111-222-3333", 
"Nick Romanov\r\n Head Crew Coach\r\n nick.nick@school.edu\r\n 123-123-1234", 
"Name Lasttt\r\n Assistant Coach")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
7L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 25L, 29L), class = "data.frame")

head(coach_info, 4)
    X1                                                                                   X2
1 <NA>                                                                   TBA\r\n Head Coach
2 <NA>                             Bobby Flowes\r\n Associate Head Women's Basketball Coach
3 <NA>                                    Jimmy Jimm\r\n Assistant Women's Basketball Coach
7 <NA> Rod Barber\r\n Head Men's Basketball Coach\r\n       (123) 456-7890Tom.Tommy@abc.edu
```

We're trying to split the `X2` column info into 4 columns for `Name`, `Title`, `Email` and `Phone`. When we `strsplit(coach_info$X2, '\r\n')`, what we get is a messy nested list, and the splitting using `\r\n` is imperfect as the `\r\n` are missing in some of the rows:

[image]
[image]
[image]

In addition to this, the inner-nested lists each have differing numbers of elements, as many rows are missing 1 or more of the name, phone number or email address:

```
> unlist(lapply(strsplit(coach_info$X2, '\r\n'), length))
 [1] 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 4 2
```

Our goal is something as close as possible to this:

```
output_df <- data.frame(
    Name = c('TBA', 'Bobby Flowes', 'Jimmy Jimm', 'Rod Barber', NA, 'Gaben Spar', 'A.B. Better', 'Nick Romanov', 'Name Lasttt'),
    Title = c('Head Coach', "Associate Head Women's Basketball Coach", "Assistant Women's Basketball Coach", "Head Men's Basketball Coach",
              NA, " Men's Basketball Graduate Assistant", "Head Women's Basketball Coach/Head Men's Golf Coach/Sports Information Associate",
              "Head Crew Coach", "Assistant Coach"),
    Email = c(NA, NA, NA, "Tom.Tommy@abc.edu", NA, "Coachgabensspar@gmail.edu", "abbetter@gmail.edu", "nick.nick@school.edu", NA),
    Phone = c(NA, NA, NA, "(123) 456-7890", NA, NA, "111-222-3333", "123-123-1234", NA),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
  

>   head(output_df, 4)
          Name                                   Title             Email          Phone
1          TBA                              Head Coach              <NA>           <NA>
2 Bobby Flowes Associate Head Women's Basketball Coach              <NA>           <NA>
3   Jimmy Jimm      Assistant Women's Basketball Coach              <NA>           <NA>
4   Rod Barber             Head Men's Basketball Coach Tom.Tommy@abc.edu (123) 456-7890
```

It seems like it may be impossible to cleanly split up the strings where no spaces or `\r\n` exist between different fields, like in the screenshots above. We're just trying to get as close as possible at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this

```
require(data.table)
setDT(coach_info)

re.phone <- '.*(\\d{3}[^[:alnum:]]*\\d{3}[^[:alnum:]]*\\d{4}).*'
re.email <- ".*[^_[:alnum:]\\-\\.]([_[:alnum:]\\-\\.]+@[[:alnum:]\\.]+).*"
re.text1 <- '([[:alnum:][:blank:]]+)\r\n([[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]+).*'


coach_info[,processed:=X2]

coach_info[grepl(re.phone,X2), phone:=gsub(re.phone,'\\1',X2)]
coach_info[!is.na(phone), processed:=gsub(phone,' ',X2,fixed=T),by=phone]

coach_info[grepl(re.email,processed), email:=gsub(re.email,'\\1',processed)]
coach_info[!is.na(email), processed:=gsub(email,' ',processed,fixed=T),by=email]

coach_info[, Name:=gsub(re.text1,'\\1',processed)]
coach_info[, Title:=gsub(re.text1,'\\2',processed)]
```

Comment: Yes this gets us 85 - 90% of the way there which is helpful. I'm not as familiar with DT as opposed to the tidyverse, but its still not too tough to follow this.

Comment: if there are any records that are not processed correctly with this code, feel free to add them to your example, and I or someone else will try to help